# Refreshing RSS data in TableView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, reloaddata

I am trying to refresh my TableView while I am parsing RSS. Once I update the xml and then I press on refresh button it wont make anything but when I close and open the app it runs the new updated xml. Where could be my problem?

```
-(void)refreshButton{

[self.MyTableView reloadData];

NSLog(@"RSS refreshed");
}
```

Thanks from now.

Comment: where are you parsing the xml ?

Comment: What do you data source methods look like?

Comment: @MidhunMP in the didStartElement.

Comment: @PhillipMills sorry I didn't understand your question

Comment: @LuaiKalkatawi: no, I'm asking where are you calling the parse method? The didStartElement method will work only after calling the parse method.

Comment: @MidhunMP I really don't understand your question

Comment: @LuaiKalkatawi: if you want to parse an XML, you need to call like: `[parser parse];` . Where did you wrote that ?

Comment: @MidhunMP In the `ViewDidLoad` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are parsing the xml from the `viewDidLoad`. So if the xml is changed then you need to parse it again.

So change the refresh data method like:

```
-(void)refreshButton
{
  NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:newXMLData];
  [parser parse];
  [self.MyTableView reloadData];
}
```

`newXMLData` is an instance of `NSData` and it holds the `XML` file in the form of bytes.

Comment: Thanks it works :)

I have small question where is the better place to parse the xml in? While I have parsed it in the `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: For the first time it is in the viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear. and another place is in the refreshing methods.

Comment: and call the [tableView reloadData] in the parserDidEndDocument method. That is the best place to reloadData

Comment: I think I have to search about the `DidEndDocument` because I am using that method.